# Django Rest Framework global timestamp

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Django model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    system = models.ForeignKey(System)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    catalog_number = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=755)
    price_usd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=2)
    price_cad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=2)
    price_eur = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=2)
    price_gbp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=2)
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

And I'm using Django Rest Framework to expose a simple API endpoint:

```
from .models import Item
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import permissions


class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    category = serializers.RelatedField(source='category')
    system = serializers.RelatedField(source='system')
    company = serializers.RelatedField(source='company')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = (
            'catalog_number',
            'price_usd',
            'price_cad',
            'price_eur',
            'price_gbp',
        )
```

My question is, I would like to include a single timestamp with json dump which would allow a consumer application to determine if the data has been updated since it was last accessed. Basically a global timestamp for when the database was last updated.

Should this be a queryset in the serializer which finds the most recent timestamp (not yet declared in the model) from the `Item` model? Or is there some setting in Django/ Rest Framework which allows determination of when the database was last updated?

Comment: Global time stamp for the entire table, database, or a time stamp for when each individual row was last updated?

Comment: For the entire database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `DateTimeField` to your model using the `auto_now` option you can order by that (decending) and limit to the first result to find the time of the latest update.

A [RetrieveAPIView](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#retrieveapiview) in which you override `get_object` to return the last updated Item together with a serialiser that just exposes the DateTimeField should give you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can you `TimeStampedModel` of `django_extensions` 
 as deacribed in [docs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_extensions.html#current-database-model-extensions)

> TimeStampedModel - An Abstract Base Class model that provides self-managed
>   created and modified fields.

```
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    ...
```

you can use `modified` field to determine when the `Item`
  last updated.